# эффект скрытия в плагине

Tags: jquery

подскажите пожалуйста почему у [этого jq-плагина](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/custom_tolltips/) не работает эффект скрытия подсказки? параметры для показа из скрипта инициализации работают, а параметры скрытия - нет

Answer (score 1):

Сами пишите? )) Ну, всё за вас оптимизировать не буду, но несколько советов дам.

Во-первых, callback-функцию вызывайте без круглых скобок и уже всё заработает:

```
// FALSE
bodyTooltip.stop(true, true).fadeIn(options.effectShowSpeed, isShowChange());
// TRUE
bodyTooltip.stop(true, true).fadeIn(options.effectShowSpeed, isShowChange);
```

Во-вторых, если вы собираетесь давать возможность выбора эффектов появления/скрытия, то лучше использовать родные эффекты jQuery (fadeIn, slideUp и т.д.) и не понадобиться делать бессмысленные 33 проверки. В вашем плагине, [увидите, где я закоментировал](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/eC2Mf/3/) груду лишнего и после написал всего одну строку, которая решает проблемку.

И еще, когда объединяете содержимое объектов (**$.extend**), не надо еще раз переопределять переменную, она и так у вас уже существует:

```
$.fn.kalininLinks = function(options) {
    options = jQuery.extend({ // var options - тут не нужно!
        bgColor: 'yellow',
        fontSize: '14px',
        /* ... */
    },options);
    /* ... */
};
```

Думаю, если хорошенько прикинуть, то код можно в раза два сократить ))

Comment: Например, так http://jsfiddle.net/kazatca/eC2Mf/4/ ))

Comment: спасибо за подсказки, но обе ваши ссылки ведут меня на страницу примерно такого вида prozaik.16mb.com/misc/dd.png
то есть исходный код мне недоступен. я что-то не так открываю?

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin, попробуйте открыть в альтернативном браузере и дождитесь, когда загрузится полностью. jsFiddle глючит иногда, может в этом была проблема.P.S. Заметил, что они поменяли интерфейс. На всякий пожарный [дублирую ссылку](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/LGm6R/).

Comment: ок спасибо, ваши примеры я с интересом разобрал. только одну строчку совсем не понял. 
bodyTooltip[options.effectHide](options.effectHideSpeed, isShowChange);
объясните пожалуйста где можно почитать про этот трюк?

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin, вот только подчеркивание там ни к чему... И никакой это не трюк )) Имея объект, а **options** таковым и является, мы же можем доставать значение как через оператор точки, так и через оператор индексатора.

    var obj = { something: 'value' }
    // или так
    obj.something => 123
    // или так
    obj['something'] => 123

Функции-методы в этом плане ничем не отличаются.